# Adding a comment to a button, with a macro assigned, in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering how you add a comment to a button in excel. So when I hold the coursor over the button, the comment will appear.

Maybe you need to do it in VBA?

Please give me the line of code needed or any other help methods and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: *when I hold the cursor over the button, the comment will appear* - that's called a *tooltip*

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/813d2338-e71f-43c9-8876-255eca4eaab4/tooltips-for-shapes-form-control-buttons-or-activex-control-buttons-in-the-spreadsheet-not-on-a?forum=excel

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the button, you can right click and get properties (while in Design Mode).  Choose View Code.  VBA will come up, and you will see the OnClick event there.

Just choose the down arrow on the right side of the screen, and you will see all of the events you can use with this button.  One of them is MouseMove.  Unfortunately, Excel is not like Access in that you can't set a MouseMove event on the detail of your form to take away the comment after they see it.  But... depending on your needs, you could pop-up a message box or something like that.

Hope that helps.